how to change default login manager on Fedora?
I have Fedora Xfce, and I was testing Budgie desktop (deleted it after few minutes) and now I have broken login screen, I'm not able to type password for default user. I need to select different user and the click on my default one (which is annoying).
How can I get back and use the default Xfce login screen?

It might be worth taking a look at the answer for XFCE Login - Auto Populate Default Username and/or the link in the first comment to the question on that page.

@DavidYockey I don't want to set default user, I want to get back my default login screen before I installed Budgie. I want to know how to change the screen, since I probably have two or more of them installed.

In /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d, see if there's a file such as 60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf. If so, see if it contains a line greeter-session= followed by a particular greeter. I'm running the Fedora Xfce Spin upgraded to version 40 and the greeter, which has never been changed, is lightdm-gtk-greeter. Assuming you have a similar config file, is its greeter different?

@DavidYockey I have this file with same content, but I also have a file 90-slick-greeter.conf with greeter-session=slick-greeter. I think that I will just try to remove this file or uninstall slick-greeter. Thanks for your help.
